# android string array nullpointerexception on older android versions

Tags: java, android

This code works fine on android 4.4, 5.0, 5.1 , 6.0

```
 File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0//Videos/");
    String[] myFiles;
    myFiles = file.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
        File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
        myFile.delete();
 }
```

But when i use this for android 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 i get java.lang.NullPointerException referring at line

```
for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++)
```

So i try to initialize the String,

```
String[] myFiles = new String[100] //just big value
```

But android studio shows initializer "new String[100]" is redundent and error is not resolved.

Why does this happen?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [File.list()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list()) says that it can return null.  You should always check for this whenever you call it and handle it correctly unless you are absolutely certain it will not return null.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not checking your folder is null or not make sure your directory contains file

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0//Videos/");
String[] myFiles;
if (file == null) {

} else {
    myFiles = file.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
        File myFile = new File(file, myFiles[i]);
         if(myFile.exists())
        myFile.delete();
    }
}
```

And if you want to delete whole directory than you can use this sample method

```
public void deleteDirectory(File file) {
if( file.exists() ) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            }
            else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,  but I still get the same error...  Phone: xperia u.  I don't get this error on zenfone 5, LG g3

Comment: Check this path /storage/emulated/0//Videos/  because some device use storage0

Comment: I tried 3 different methods to delete, all didn't work.. If I try to get names of files in the directory, it doesn't show... I have declared permission to read  and write external storage.. So what it could be?

Comment: Or is the file.list() method  not working? Because the file names are not displayed by System out.println() method....? Could this also be possible?